# Jquery OnChange event not firing

Tags: jquery

```
$('.minSimiTrack').Slider({
   accept : '.minSimiHandle', fractions : 30,
     onSlide : function( cordx, cordy, x , y){
     $("#wrapperMinSimi").css("background-position", ((cordx))+"px 0px");
    .....},
      onChange : function(){
    $('#submitResetFooter').show(); 
    },
    .....

 HTML markup
       <div id="wrapperMinSimi">
   <div class="minSimiTrack"><div class="minSimiHandle"></div></div>    
   </div>
```

I don't know why onChange not working....

Comment: 1- which kind of slider? 2- can u post some html markup so we can help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume this is using jQuery UI slider? In which case your initial call has an erroneous  capital S, and the event names are wrong.

```
$('.minSimiTrack').slider({
    accept : '.minSimiHandle', 
    fractions : 30,
    slide : function( cordx, cordy, x , y){
        $("#wrapperMinSimi").css("background-position", ((cordx))+"px 0px");
        .....
    },
    change : function(){
        $('#submitResetFooter').show(); 
    },
    .....
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jQuery UI, the on slide and on change events are "slide" and "change" respectively. i.e.

```
$( ".selector" ).slider({
   change: function(event, ui) { ... }
});
```

From here

http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#event-slide